# Merge two consecutive rows if values complement each other

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions

Say I have table, the column `c` is ordered ASC, table contains null value

```
id  a    b    c   d   
1  'a1' 'b1'  1  'd1'
2  'a2' 'b2'  2
3             5  'd3'
4  'a4' 'b4'  6  'd4'
5  'a5' 'b5'  7  
6             8  'b6'
```

It needs to be processed in a way that,

1. if two rows 'compliment' each other(like id=2 and id=3)
2. the difference of c value of two rows is <= 1 (like id=7 and id=8)

1) and 2) is fulfilled at the same time then two rows should be combined upwards into one

id=7 and id=8 combined into

```
5  'a5'  'b5'  7   'b6'
```

and the `id=6` row should be dropped. How can this be implemented in Postgres?

Comment: I do not understand. None of your rows have id 7 or 8, and only row 1 has c<=1

Comment: Does "compliment [sic] each other" mean that `a is not null and b is not null and d is null` in one row, and `a is null and b is null and d is not null` in the other row?

Comment: What would happen with an additional row `7  'a7' 'b7'  9 `, which would also complement row 6?

Comment: @harmic sorry should be the difference<=1

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter thanks always aggregate upwards, left the remainder remainder

Comment: @MikeSherrill'CatRecall' compliment means they can combine to one row exactly, no more no less